# How do you mean vs What do you mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What do people mean when they say

> How do you mean?

Are they asking me to explain what I just said? Then how is it different from

> What do you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*What do you mean?* is commonly known and usually said when one does not comprehend what the other said. Basically it is asking for a repeat of the sentence in more detail.

*How do you mean?* is a little different. *How* can be defined as ***in what way or manner***.

> How does this work?
>
> In what way or manner does this work?

Both sentences are basically the same. So, *How do you mean?* is asking:

> In what way or manner do you mean?

Comment: Could you give an example where responses to the two would be different?

Comment: Here are some nice examples: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-do-you-mean-or-how-do-you-mean.2082915/  //  Also note that in some contexts "What do you mean?" can be a bit more confrontational.